# How do I use an existing MongoDB in a Meteor project?

Tags: meteor

Let's say there is a running MongoDB server for a GUI client (by [wxPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxPython)) for a while.

How could I connect my new Meteor project to my **already existing MongoDB**?

Comment: Dror (http://stackoverflow.com/users/460278/dror) has the correct answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12996674/1114274

Comment: Thanks for comment. I know @Dror's solution is much official instead of a hack, but I have already assigned an answer before. I'm not quite sure if it is a good and allowable behavior to change/update "answer" then?

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me this. I'm more confident now.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use the environment variable MONGO_URL. 
Something like:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/your_db
```

Replace `your_db` with `meteor` or whatever db you want to use.

Comment: I'm stuck. Can you explain how to Replace your_db with "meteor"

Comment: note that this will NOT work on prod if deploying to meteor -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971036/mongodb-meteor-export-mongo-url-to-deployed-applications

Comment: @SurjithSM `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name` will put data in a database named `my_database_name`. He meant that if you want, you can do `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor`. Tought I would advise naming your database name the same as your project.

Comment: Can it be done with some configuration file? Tried with settings.json and it won't work

Comment: this crashed the heck out of my local app.

Comment: Be AWARE: The collections may look empty, you would need to make an insert in order to see the data.

Answer (score 15):

We use `npm`:

- Create a `package.json` file with `npm init`, if you don't have one already.
- Enter and modify the following line in that file (replacing all the `<...>`'s):

```
"scripts": {"meteor": "MONGO_URL=mongodb://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVER>:<PORT>/<DB> meteor"}
```

- You can then start *meteor* with just `npm run meteor`

Comment: 'MONGO_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: it's an environment variable, make sure there are no spaces around the = sign

Answer (score 9):

In [the comments to danny's answer Tom Wijsman recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588038/how-to-use-the-existing-mongodb-in-a-meteor-project#comment13738623_10593624) patching packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js, line 21. A better place is in app/meteor/run.js, line 460. This way the environment variable is still picked up if present, such as when running Meteor on Heroku. Just change the default hardcoded mongodb://127.0.0.1 to the location of your MongoDB server.

Answer (score 4):

You can use db.copyDatabase to do this, with a caveat that there is a bug and you can't update the data in Meteor. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/61

If you're using the development version of Meteor, you can transfer data from a running MongoDB server by starting your Meteor app, then doing:

```
mongo --port 3002
```

This will connect you to the Meteor app's Mongo server. Now use db.copyDatabase like this:

```
db.copyDatabase('myappDatabase', 'meteor', 'localhost');
```

This will copy the database myappDatabase from a MongoDB server running on the standard port on localhost, to the Meteor app Mongo server. The database name the Meteor app uses is 'meteor'.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the data to the Meteor MongoDB database - no reason to try to hook Meteor up to the existing database and risk overwriting things.

Use `mongoexport` to dump your collections individually, then `mongoimport` to import the files into the database named `meteor` in the Meteor MongoDB instance. The Meteor MongoDB instance runs on port 3002 with bind_address 127.0.0.1, and the data files are in the Meteor project subdirectory `.meteor/local/db`.

See [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-DataImportandExport) if you're not familiar with import/export in MongoDB.

Comment: Does that mean we should deliver mongodb hosting to meteor instead of hosting by other means?

Comment: @Drake: Unless you can adjust Meteor to work with your database. `app/lib/mongo_runner.js` decides how to launch it (you might not even require launching code, thus look into how to disable it). The connection to it seems to happen inside `packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js`, I think you can simply change the url parameter on line 21. If you want to know its value, insert `console.log(url);` on the line before that, restart Meteor and watch your Meteor output closely. Make sure you do indeed call Meteor once in your app for it to trigger...

Comment: @Drake: If you want me to place my comment as an answer (if it worked for you), please let me know.

Comment: @TomWijsman: I tried `console.log(url);` and got the info! I'll suggest you to make this as complete as a work-around answer cause I believe it does provide help to the community, or at least, people like me not familiar with meteor yet~

Comment: heck of a lot easier to use mongochef to copy and paste data, rather than the export/import commands. http://3t.io/mongochef/

Answer (score 0):

All I did was add the IP of my Digital ocean droplet server, instead of localhost, and it worked:

```
env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://yourdomain.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://104.236.24.66:27017/meteor',
      PORT: 3002,
    },
```

---

EDIT:
use MUP to deploy your meteor projects: https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up

```
env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'https://www.example.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
    },
```

Mup uses Docker, and will "link" your 2 containers, thus hosting both the app and mongo on the same VM (server). Your mongoDB shouldn't be accessible from the public IP for security reasons.

Comment: where did you add this?

Comment: it's actually bad practice to use the public IP of your VM for the mongoDB, im going to update my answer to use localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of time and found out that it requires quotes around the URL:

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost/meteor'
export MONGO_OPLOG_URL='op log url'
```

Answer (score -8):

You have to keep your app running in one terminal window then open another and type "meteor mongo" and it should work!