# On Mac what is the best Data GUI for Meteor and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have looked into a few different GUI's including Robomongo, but I can't seem to get it connected to my Meteor database.  Can someone please tell me what the best GUI is to use and how to implement it?  I can't seem to find any guides online.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588038/how-to-use-the-existing-mongodb-in-a-meteor-project

Comment: Robomongo works well, what problem are you having with it?

Answer (score 6):

**To connect using umongo:**

1. In your terminal, run the following (make sure you're in your project directory):

   ```
   meteor mongo --url someappname.meteor.com
   ```

   Note: This assumes your app is being hosted by meteor. If accessing a local db, leave off everything after --url

   The output should look like this:

   ```
   mongodb://client:1234-abcd-1234-abcd-1234567890@production-db-a1.meteor.io:27017/yourappname_meteor_com
   ```
2. In umongo, go to File > Connect and enter that string in the URI field. Hit Enter.
3. To view documents within a collection, navigate to that collection in the sidebar and highlight the collection you want to view.
4. To view all documents in that collection, click on Documents > Find. Leave all fields blank and hit OK.

I've found umongo decent for viewing large collections, but the Meteor URI expires quickly and umongo will start throwing errors.

NOTE: You'll likely only be able to view files for a minute or two, so while the above will get you connected, it may not be of much use for more than simply viewing your collections (why not use terminal at that point?). For that reason, I suspect imslavko's suggestion of using z-mongo-admin is going to be the way to go when/if the project matures.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a UI to look at Mongo database contents there are couple of options.

If you want something Meteor specific, take a look at this atmosphere package: [Houston Admin](https://atmospherejs.com/houston/admin). It is a 3rd party package built by the community.

For more general solution take a look at [genghis](https://github.com/bobthecow/genghis), ruby gem with nice UI.

Comment: By the way, z-mongo-admin was created on Meteor Summer Hackathon.

Comment: Houston Admin is a great package for managing your Meteor apps database.  Thanks for the heads up @imslavko. As you mentioned, it was made for the meteor community by the meteor community and just works without having to set up any custom config files.  btw, I upvoted the answer because it actually provides a Meteor specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

I like mongohub on mac. Feels very mac :-)
Link here: [github](https://github.com/jeromelebel/MongoHub-Mac)

Comment: From my experience, Mac Hub crashes a lot for my taste. RoboMongo seems to be the most stable solution.

Comment: The link is the stable and still updated forked version, not the official.
Never crashes and just minimalistic yet complete enough for me.
It only misses the ability to tell which version of monod you're connected to.