# MONGO_URL doesn't work with meteor reset

Tags: mongodb, meteor

[You can use `MONGO_URL`env variable to tell meteor to connect to your instance of mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996674/311744). Great.

For instance:

`MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/my_project meteor` works. I see the new documents in my robomongo on localhost in a database named `my_project`.

But if I do:

`MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/my_project meteor reset`, the database `my_project` stays unchanged. `meteor reset`ing works when I use the meteor-provided mongodb (when I don't supply `MONGO_URL`).

**Things I tried:**

- `EXPORT`ing `MONGO_URL` instead of putting it in front of the command. Doesn't help.

Also to what mongo instance do meteor connects to if I just run `meteor` (the default one) ? I can't find any meteor database on my localhost

Comment: To open robomongo on default mongo server created by meteor: In robomongo: `File > Connect > Create > name: 'Meteor default', address: 'localhost:3001' > Connect`. Your collections are in `Meteor > collections`. `meteor` server must be started for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a `MONGO_URL`, then mongo will create a database in your .meteor directory tree and run it on `127.0.0.1:3001`. The `mongo reset` command seems to just remove the local files for those. To reset your external mongo db for your meteor app you can just remove the `my_project` db: `mongo my_project` -> `db.dropDatabase()`.

Comment: Thanks. I would have loved to be able to `meteor reset` on my specific database `my_database`. Is there a way ?

Comment: Meteor does run `127.0.0.1:3001` once my meteor server is started. I could connect robomongo to it. This is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code for the 'reset' command

```
if (options.args.length !== 0) {
  process.stderr.write(
    "meteor reset only affects the locally stored database.\n" +
    "\n" +
    "To reset a deployed application use\n" +
    "  meteor deploy --delete appname\n" +
    "followed by\n" +
   "  meteor deploy appname\n");
  return 1;
}
```