# mup setup/deploy - ECONNREFUSED on 127.0.0.1

Tags: vagrant, meteor-up, vagrant-windows

I'm trying to `mup deploy` the `todos` example of Meteor to a Vagrant VM running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64.

[Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) supports Windows (I'm on Windows 7):

> You can use install and use Meteor Up from Linux, Mac and **Windows**.

This is my `c:\code\todos\mup.json`:

```js
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 2222,
            "username": "vagrant",
            "password": "vagrant"
        }
    ],
    "setupMongo": true,
    "setupNode": true,
    "nodeVersion": "0.12.4",
    "setupPhantom": true,
    "enableUploadProgressBar": false,
    "appName": "todos-app",
    "app": "/code/todos",
    "env": {
        "ROOT_URL": "http://127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "3001", // The port you want to bind to on your server.
        "UPSTART_UID": "vagrant" // The user you want to run meteor as.
    },
    "deployCheckWaitTime": 30
}
```

My Vagrant VM is up and PuTTYTray is connected via vagrant:vagrant@127.0.0.7:2222. Yet `mup deploy` fails:

```
C:\code\todos>mup deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

" Checkout Kadira!
  It's the best way to monitor performance of your app.
  Visit: https://kadira.io/mup "

Building Started: /code/todos
? Can't build for mobile on Windows. Skipping the following platforms:
  android, ios

Started TaskList: Deploy app 'todos-app' (linux)
[127.0.0.1] - Uploading bundle
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

Same for `mup setup`. And in the VM `mup deploy` encounters a ["weird error"](https://gist.github.com/CTimmerman/ae285b5466f6f99f0cb6#file-weird_error-log).

Should I [downgrade](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/396) `mup`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading `mup` doesn't help:

```
C:\code\todos>npm install -g mup@0.9.7
C:\Users\Cees.Timmerman\AppData\Roaming\npm\mup -> C:\Users\Cees.Timmerman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup\bin\mup
mup@0.9.7 C:\Users\Cees.Timmerman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup
├── colors@0.6.2
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── uuid@1.4.2
├── async@0.9.2
├── rimraf@2.4.0 (glob@4.5.3)
├── cjson@0.3.1 (jsonlint@1.6.0)
└── nodemiral@0.3.11 (debug@0.7.4, ejs@0.8.8, handlebars@1.0.12)

C:\code\todos>mup -v

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

sshpass required for password based authentication: refer http://git.io/_vHbvQ

C:\code\todos>mup deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

sshpass required for password based authentication: refer http://git.io/_vHbvQ
```

[SSHPass](https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979) doesn't work on Windows.

Manually setting up my Meteor app worked with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25945966/819417).