# unexpected mongo exit code 100 with meteor on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, meteor, cmd

I am keep getting this error message when I run "meteor" on cmd on windows.

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught expection.
This can be caused by MongoDB being unable to write to a local database. 
Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. mongoDB does not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking.
```

This happens right after I downloaded meteor and created my first project. I already tried resetting the project. I saw people recommend removing the lock file in db folder. However, when I check `.meteor/local/db`, its empty.

Comment: some people say `meteor reset` helped them, If it doesn't work for you can try restarting your computer if there is an active lock on the db it will be released or try running your `cmd` console as an admin

Comment: I already tired restarting my computer and running my console as an admin :(

Comment: Do you have another instance of mongodb installed ?

Comment: @gatolgaj I am not sure about meaning of "instance". I only downloaded meteor. I never installed mongodb itself

Comment: Please check this [link on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712468/cant-create-working-meteor-js-project-on-a-vagrant-box) .

Comment: I had a similar problem from my system locale, when i had anything else than en_US it wouldnt start.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to reset Meteor.

   ```
   -Meteor reset
   -Meteor
   ```
2. Update Meteor.

   ```
   -meteor update --release 1.4.0.1
   ```
3. Your *username* could be the problem.

In my case, it works fine when I moved the project's folder to other user's folder.

Answer (score 0):

> Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. mongoDB does not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking.

This is probably your problem.

If you use GitHub for your project, I'd strongly recommend you clone your project from GitHub into your Documents directory, and try running `meteor` again from there.

Don't copy your existing folder to Documents, because you'll just copy the existing busted permissions. If you're not familiar with the Windows folder permissions model, you're going to have a bad time dealing with this problem.