# Meteor reset not working in vagrant

Tags: javascript, meteor, vagrant, hashicorp-otto

I'm trying to get meteor reset to work in vagrant box. However I kept getting errors. This is my error message:

> /home/vagrant/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.8ogiso++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
>                         throw(ex);
>                               ^ Error: EBUSY, rmdir '/vagrant/foosboom-meteor/.meteor/local'
>       at Object.Future.wait (/home/vagrant/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.8ogiso++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
>       at Object.rm_recursive (/tools/fs/files.js:270:9)
>       at Command.main.registerCommand.name [as func] (/tools/cli/commands.js:1211:9)
>       at /tools/cli/main.js:1378:23

I'm using hashicorp [Otto](https://www.ottoproject.io/) as my development environment.

I have performed a [mount on the local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712468/cant-create-working-meteor-js-project-on-a-vagrant-box) as suggested by one of the user here.

Any idea what seems to be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After mounting you can't reset your mongo so do this

```
 sudo umount -f /vagrant/foosboom-meteor/.meteor/local
```