# Get data from remote server and observe changes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a mongodb hosted somewhere with the collection.

In my meteor application I want to get the data from that server and I want to publish the documents in that collection and I want to subscribe to that collection and

whenever the data changes in remote server I want to send the records to clients which is a normal meteor behaviour.

How to do this in meteor? Can anybody give example or give links to tuts.

Comment: Take a look here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588038/how-to-use-the-existing-mongodb-in-a-meteor-project

Comment: I dont know anything about Meteor, but I think it will help if you knew how this behavior is accomplished under the covers -- search for MongoDB and "tailable cursors" -- this technique creates the impression that you are subscribing to collection changes.