# MongoDB is unable to write to a local database in docker from boot2docker

Tags: mongodb, meteor, docker, boot2docker

Basically I'd like to run meteor in a ubuntu docker on os x, and use atom to edit the source code. So I use shared volume to achieve this.

I use virtualbox 4.3.30 and boot2docker 1.71.

The meteor app runs well when it's NOT in the shared volume.
But if I put it in the shared volume, it says:

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.   
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.   
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.   
Can't start Mongo server.                     
MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
This can be caused by MongoDB being unable to write to a local database.
Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. MongoDB does
not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking.
```

The command I use to run the docker is

```
docker run -t -i -p 3000:3000 -v ~/Documents/myapp:/home/myapp -d ubuntu
```

My question is how I can have the meteor app run mongodb successfully in the shared volume?

---

I have tried 'meteor reset' and remove the lock file in .meteor, none of them work.

Comment: I guess you have a Linux MongoDB, what is the file system of your shared volume? Maybe MongoDB can't write on such a filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the mongodb does not support share NFS file type. The boot2docker uses NFS. You can try to use the share of the virtual box files, instructions in https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions.

Another alternative would be to use the [azk](http://azk.io), which make part of the core team.
Note: For now only Mac OS X and Linux

Comment: Thanks. I just use mongolab then don't have the problem anymore.  Refer this to know how to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588038/how-to-use-the-existing-mongodb-in-a-meteor-project