# meteor not subscribing to data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am doing something wrong in my Meteor app but simply cannot find out what it is. I'm not receiving any data in the UI. Here's the code.

lib/common.js

```
Data = new Meteor.Collection('data2');
```

'data2' is a collection I created and responds fine in mongo shell

server/app.js

```
Meteor.publish("Data", function() {
        return Data.find({});
    });
```

client/app.js

```
Meteor.subscribe("Data");
```

client/helpers.js

```
Template.home.helpers({

    results: function(){
     return Data.find();

}
});
```

I've even tried with specifying the two columns-field1, 2 in find() to no avail.

client/home.html

```
<template name="home">
<table class="table table-striped tablesorter z-depth-5">
    <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="15%">field1</th>
              <th width="15%">field2</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            {{#each results}}
            <tr>
            <td>{{field1}}</td>
            <td>{{field2}}</td>          
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Inspection findings -

```
Data.find().fetch()
[]
```

Comment: Just for grins do `Meteor.publish('myData',...)` and `Meteor.subscribe('myData')` to rule out problems with multiple uses of the name `Data`

Comment: Changed 'Data' var to 'myData' - still no dice.

Comment: `Meteor.Collection` is now `Mongo.Collection`, though this isn't your problem. When you say "Inspection findings" do you mean you ran that in the web console?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in what you're doing. Try putting the *autopublish* package back in and see if the data shows up. Then you can narrow down the problem to your publication or subscription.

Comment: @DavidWeldon - yes - in web console.

Comment: @MichelFloyd - added it. No difference.

Comment: Do you get a record count from the mongo console?  `db.data2.find().count()`

Comment: @MarkLeiber - 0 in web console and 4 in mongo shell (there are 4 docs in the DB)

Comment: Is there a way to check if Meteor is connecting with the DB? There is only one db - 'local' and i've done `set MONGO_URL= ` . Also tried with the url as ` mongodb:\\localhost\local `- but same results.

Comment: well that's got to be part of the problem; neither of these MONGO_URLs are valid. either not set it, or set it to `mongodb://127.0.0.1/something`

Comment: @ChristianFritz - tried it with `mongodb://127.0.0.1/local` as well as with nothing as in `set MONGO_URL= `  and with just `set MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1 ` . Same thing.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588038/how-to-use-the-existing-mongodb-in-a-meteor-project.  Namely, `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:your_port/local`

Comment: @MarkLeiber - tried it. with both localhost and 127.0.0.1. Just checked - in MongoVue - the serverInfo shows Host as something else - like for example `ZBCD321YU` . Tried it with that host as well, nothing's working. Also, on `myData.find()` in the web console, I get `L…n.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, _selectorId: undefined`  with `data2` mentioned in that same web console tree - so it is able to go up to the `new Mongo.collection('data2')` but don't know if beyond that to the DB or something's not letting it subscribe?

Comment: Update: Set Mongo_url to a remote server and it works. (not trying with localhost for now). But now, it displays just 1 row whereas it should be displaying a dozen. What could be the issue? Everything's the same except for the mongo_url and Mongo.collection. (Would also like to point out that I am coming from a Python b/g and this is my 1st time with Meteor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The mistake I was making was that I was calling the 'local' DB from the c:\data\db directory created when I installed mongodb on my system. But the meteor db is not located there but resides in /.meteor. Upon correction, it works.